# Rails Simple_form HAML Error: No route matches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, simple-form, simple-form-for

~~~ Solution found! ~~~
I changed my def new method in jean_controller.rb to

```
def new
    @jean = Jean.create(params[:id])
end
```

and capitalized my Model and Description inside my _form partial (to match the capitalize Model and Description inside my migration file)

Thanks for all the help everyone!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So I have looked extensively for a solution to my problem, but to no avail. It drove me to create an account specifically to ask this question. I am using rails 4.2.0

I am using this tutorial https://mackenziechild.me/12-in-12/4/ to build a Pinterest clone, but I run into this error with my _form.html.haml partial:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Jeans#new
>   /app/views/jeans/_form.html.haml where line #1 raised:
>   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"jeans"} missing required keys: [:id]

I've tried a variety of solutions with input_html:, changing my models, jeans_controller...etc

Here is my partial code: (the first line is indented correctly, but I don't know how to get it to display properly on stackoverflow)

```
= simple_form_for @jean, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
- if @jean.errors.any?
    #errors
        %h2
            = pluralize(@jean.errors.count, "error")
            prevented this Jean Model from saving
        %ul
            - @jean.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                %li= msg

.form-group
    = f.input :model, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

.form-group
    = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

.form-group
    = f.input :price, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

and here is my controller code:

```
class JeansController < ApplicationController

def index
end

def show
    @jean=Jean.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @jean = Jean.new
end

def create
    @jean = Jean.new(jean_params)
end

private

def jean_params
    params.require(:jean).permit(:model, :description, :price)
end
end
```

and my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :jeans
  root "jeans#index"
end
```

Can anyone help me? :(:

Comment: Do you have any link in your `_form` partial to your `jean`? like to show it?

Comment: I just have: (ignore the ; it represents the next line)

    %h1 New Jeans;
= render 'form';
= link_to "Back", root_path

Comment: I found the solution! I changed my def new method to
 def new
  @jean = Jean.create(params[:id])
 end
and edited my _form to capitalize Model and Description because it is capitalized in my migration file.

Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: This solution started to create empty records in my database, how did you avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a show action in your controller to show the newly posted jean, basically add this to your controller :

```
def show
  @jean=Jean.find(params[:id])
end
```

You also need to change your create action to

```
def create
  @jean = Jean.create(jean_params)
end
```

Comment: I applied that change (preventing a future error, thank you!) but the current error is still there.

Comment: try chaging your create action to def create
    @jean = Jean.create(jean_params)
end

Comment: Please show your routes.rb file, post it to the question

Comment: did you try changing the create action?